# Which design pattern should be used?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a some functionality implemented to store documents inside a data base.

Now, I want to access the functionality in my module but not directly.

As I have the FileInputStream with me and the functionality implemented accepts JSON string.

So, which design pattern could be used to bridge the gap in input parameters?

I know **Adapter** is one of the answers but can anyone suggest anything else?

Below is the sample of the functionality.

```
public interface DocumentService {

    public String create(String jsonRequest);

    public String search(String jsonRequest);

    public String update(String jsonRequest);

    public String fetch(String jsonRequest);

}
```

Comment: ... Don't get hung up on what it's called or what official design pattern it is. This isn't rocket science, you need something that goes from an FIS to json.

Comment: @DaveNewton I surely know that something has to be done to convert from FIS to JSON. I am just asking whether the Adapter is the only correct choice? Or even it is a correct choice at all?

Comment: Why do you care what it's called? Why don't you make an object that does what you need, and either compose a new object with both, or whatever fits your precise usage pattern (or does eventually, there's nothing that says you have to get it right the first time), and move on? You're getting hung up on nothing helpful: iterate and move forward.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Your comments are more appropriate as an answer.

Comment: Adapter pattern could work!

Answer (score 2):

To elucidate my comments:

1. Trying to wedge every bit of functionality into an explicit "pattern" isn't a productive use of your time.
2. Even if it is, trying to find the perfect "name" for what you actually come up with isn't.
3. You need a helper class that converts an `FIS` into JSON, and that's about it.
4. You could compose a service that uses that helper and your existing class, or...
5. Compose your existing class into the FIS => JSON converter, or...
6. Modify your data flow so that you pass the data through a filter that JSONifies it, or...

In other words, (a) the "best" answer depends on your very specific situation, and (b) it doesn't matter what it's called. *Do* something, put it somewhere half-way reasonable, and if it ends up not being exactly right, iterate until it is. Don't waste time trying to name the "pattern".

It's like throws and joint locks: don't look for them, find them. The patterns are hidden in your application, surface them and implement.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a private converting method

```
String toJSON(FileInputStream fs) {
   ...
}
```

If you happen to need that method in multiple locations move it into a utility class.

If that single method is not flexible enough for every situation you need it in **right now** then you should consider writing an adapter class.

The desire to design a perfect, flawless architecture for every functionality is natural in many programmers. It poses the risk of paralyzing the actual objective, which is to deliver a working product.

The important thing about good design is not that it fulfills every possible use case that may arise in the future, but that it is easy to understand and easy to change should that use case actually arrive.

Comment: Personally I'd lean away from this, instead breaking up classes that do very different things.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Adapter is a good choice. I will move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the DAO pattern?

Pass the input stream to the DAO object and make it convert it from the file input stream to JSON and call the create methods.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm